# How many times in EPL did a title deciding final game of the season take place between two title chasing teams?

Tags: football, trivia, records

Referring only to the Premier League era (since 1992), how many times did it occur that two title challengers faced each other in the last game of the season to decide the fate of the trophy (i.e. both teams were in contention of the title till that point)?

P.S: I am not sure but I read somewhere that as the season comes to an end the FA tries to change the fixtures to make the top table teams play against each other during closing stages to make it more dramatic. (The 2007 Manchester United vs Chelsea final game reschedule was such an attempt but by the time that game came up Manchester United had already won the league)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it has never occurred in the Premier League era.

It had occurred, however, just 3 years before the Premier League started. In the final day of the 1988/89 English First Division season, Arsenal were playing Liverpool at Anfield and required a 2-0 victory to snatch the title from Liverpool's hands. Arsenal managed to pull it off as [Michael Thomas scored an injury time goal](http://www.arsenal.com/news/news-archive/anfield-89-match-details) to give Arsenal the title in one of the most dramatic finishes to a season in English top-flight history.